# Javascript : Stop setInterval using clearInterval

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I have seen this question asked many times here (atleast 6) with answers ranging from improper use of a variable to improper scope. However, I still cannot get clearInterval to stop my timer.

I will post the full code below - but I am looking to do something very simple. I am just trying to have code refresh an image (in mapbox) until another image is selected. The other image will load but the timer doesn't stop so it keeps refreshing the old image.

1. I set a global variable named "refreshtimerA" to hold the setInterval.
2. In addKEWX_REFLECTIVITY_toA(), this function runs the timer and refreshes an image in that window (it's a weather map) by use of a nested function called refreshKEWXL2REFLECTIVITY_A(). This works.
3. When the user activates the function addGOES_16_toA(), it should (as I added) activate clearInterval(refreshtimerA); But this does not stop it.

I have tried so many variations and sifted through here but I cannot find a working answer. I hope to clear this up as my whole project is completely stalled over something that should be simple. My code :

edit : link to dropbox complete html/js example: https://www.dropbox.com/s/11y2i859csj3o6k/stackoverflow.zip?dl=0

```
var refreshtimerA;

function clearAllPaneA() {
  topleftmapbox.setLayoutProperty('overlay_KEWX_L2_REFLECTIVITY', 'visibility', 'none');
  topleftmapbox.setLayoutProperty('overlay_GOES_16_CH02', 'visibility', 'none');
  document.getElementById("reflectivityBar").style.visibility = "visible";
}

function addKEWX_REFLECTIVITY_toA(){
  clearAllPaneA();
  refreshtimerA = setInterval(refreshKEWXL2REFLECTIVITY_A, 5000); // 5 second constantly refreshes (works as the code is)
  topleftmapbox.setLayoutProperty('overlay_KEWX_L2_REFLECTIVITY', 'visibility', 'visible');
  document.getElementById("ReflectivityBar").style.visibility = "visible";


  function refreshKEWXL2REFLECTIVITY_A() {
    topleftmapbox.removeLayer('overlay_KEWX_L2_REFLECTIVITY');
    topleftmapbox.removeSource('source_KEWX_L2_REFLECTIVITY');

    topleftmapbox.addSource("source_KEWX_L2_REFLECTIVITY", {
      "type": "image",
      "url": "images/KEWX_L2_REFLECTIVITY.gif",
      "coordinates": [
        [-103.009641, 33.911],  
        [-94.009641, 33.911],   
        [-94.009641, 24.911], 
        [-103.009641, 24.911] 
      ]
    })

    var layers = topleftmapbox.getStyle().layers;
    // Find the index of the first symbol layer in the map style
    var firstSymbolId;
    for (var i = 0; i < layers.length; i++) {
      if (layers[i].type === 'symbol') {
        firstSymbolId = layers[i].id;
        break;
      }
    }

    topleftmapbox.addLayer({
      "id": "overlay_KEWX_L2_REFLECTIVITY",
      "source": "source_KEWX_L2_REFLECTIVITY",
      "type": "raster",
      "raster-opacity": 0.5,
      "layout": {"visibility": "visible"},
    }, firstSymbolId)
  }
}

function addGOES_16_toA(){
  clearInterval(refreshtimerA); // does not work
  clearAllPaneA();
  topleftmapbox.setLayoutProperty('overlay_GOES_16_CH02', 'visibility', 'visible');
}
```

Comment: You should strongly consider using indentation while writing code - it'll make reading and debugging it much easier. (tons of repeated newlines doesn't help much either)

Comment: Is it possible that addKEWX_REFLECTIVITY_toA() is called multiple times without calls to addGOES_16_toA() in between, so that the variable refreshTimerA gets overwritten with a new value?

Comment: I am still new here and I can't get code to post without formatting it 4 chars in. So I hacked it in notepad just to post this. Once I figure out how to do that better, I will be able to indent here. I lost some of the formatting before I posted.

Comment: `addKEWX_REFLECTIVITY_toA` is never called in your code

Comment: addKEWX_REFLECTIVITY_toA() can only be called once, so I know this isn't doing it.

Comment: And to clarify, addKEWX_REFLECTIVITY_toA()  and addGOES_16_toA() are called from the HTML file.

Comment: @David Are they called by user input? If there are multiple ```addKEWX_REFLECTIVITY_toA()``` calls without ```addGOES_16_toA()``` calls in-between this might be the problem.

Comment: I fixed your indentation (you can press more than 4 spaces here) - `refreshKEWXL2REFLECTIVITY_A` is nested inside `addKEWX_REFLECTIVITY_toA` on purpose or by accident plz?

Comment: They are called by user input (just a menu button), but I have only called it once. I checked this multiple times also. I am stumped.

Comment: Thank you for the indentation fix. refreshKEWXL2REFLECTIVITY_A() is nested on purpose. If it needs to be outside of  addKEWX_REFLECTIVITY_toA() to work, that is OK.

Comment: nested should be fine here.. can you confirm in which order `addKEWX_REFLECTIVITY_toA` vs `addGOES_16_toA` are called? e.g. add a `console.log` on top of each

Comment: I have added a dropbox link. If you open the HTML file and click "MRMS" it shows the image in the top left map and it refreshes constantly. If you click "GOES-16" under it, it changes but is immediately changed by the timer that does not stop from the other image. I know the HTML is a super mess! I don't think the problem is in it, but if it is I hope someone can find it. I am not great with this.

Comment: They can be called in any manner. You can see in the example I linked to. "MRMS is addKEWX_REFLECTIVITY_toA and GOES-16 is addGOES_16_toA, both under the "KEWX" menu category

Comment: they shouldn't be, `clearInterval` **must** be called before replacing `refreshtimerA` with a new value, otherwise you will lose the old value and won't be able to stop it

Comment: I should be clear, when the user clicks a button for a new image to appear - I want to immediately call clearInterval. That is what I am trying to do with addGOES_16_toA. - this way it is always cleared no matter what the user selects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must ensure `clearInterval` is called before replacing the value of `refreshtimerA`, e.g.:

```
<li><a title="" onclick="addGOES_16_toA(); addKEWX_REFLECTIVITY_toA();">GOES-16 then MRMS</a></li>
```

Comment: This does not seem to work. I call addKEWX_REFLECTIVITY_toA(), then I call addGOES_16_toA(). Before *anything* happens in addGOES_16_toA(), it immediately calls clearInterval. I do not even have working code inside of addGOES_16_toA() to interfere with this yet. I cannot get the timer to stop under any circumstance.

Comment: I have also tried another function called stopTimer that calls clearInterval and *only* does that. But it still does not stop it.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about.. the code of `addGOES_16_toA` is posted here to your question including `clearInterval(refreshtimerA)`, the code of `addKEWX_REFLECTIVITY_toA` here in question contains assignment to `refreshtimerA` and I am stating the fact that the clearInterval must be called **before** the assignment of a new value + I added a code example related to the HTML from your dropbox link... if you have different question, please formulate your question in a way that can be answered, thank you

Comment: Yes, thank you! I tried what you were telling me but I added a syntax error in the process causing it to still fail. You have solved this for me, thank you! This now works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

May that example helps you solve the problem

```js
var t; // timer id

var buttonStart = document.querySelector("#start");
var buttonStop = document.querySelector("#stop");

var timerDiv = document.querySelector("#timer");

buttonStart.onclick = function(){
  timerDiv.innerText = "Wait 3 seconds...";
  
 t = setTimeout(function(){
   timerDiv.innerText = "OK";
    t = null;
  }, 3000);
  
}

buttonStop.onclick = function(){

  if(t){
    clearTimeout(t);
    t = null;
    timerDiv.innerText = "Stoped";
  } else {
    timerDiv.innerText = "It no timer";
  }

}
```

```html
<div id="timer">unset</div>

<div>
  <input type="button" id="start" value="start">
</div>

<div>
  <input type="button" id="stop" value="stop">
</div>
```